# Proof verification regarding weak-continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

I want to prove that

For $V$ a normed space, $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ a linear form that is continuous with respect to the weak topology, f is strongly continuous.

By definition, the weak topology is the coarsest set such that the family of seminorms
$ \{ g : g \in V^* \} $ is continuous. Now, in my lecture, we have defined the dual $V^*$ to be the space of all linear bounded functionals, and hence, any open set in the weak topology is also open in the norm topology. Therefore, $f$ is strongly continuous, since the preimage of any open set in $\mathbb{K}$ is open with respect to the weak topology and consequently open in norm topology.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: I am aware this might seem obvious to many people, but I wanted to make sure with this post that I had a correct understanding of the terms involved. The uploaded solution to the problem takes a completely different path, so I am not sure whether this works, any comment, even extremly short ones, are welcomed

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/735198).